# How is a Log4j2 JDBCAppender used to insert into a date column?

Tags: jdbc, appender, log4j2

I am trying to use Log4j2's [JDBCAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) to insert a value into an Oracle date column.  I know how to use isEventTimestamp, but I need to insert a date from the ThreadContext.

I'm guessing I'm not formatting the date correctly, but I can't find any documentation on how to correctly format.

How I'm formatting Date:

```
ThreadContext.put("DATE_VALUE", new Date().toString());
```

This is the Log4j2 JDBCAppender Column element I'm using:

```
<Column name="DATE_COLUMN" pattern="%X{DATE_VALUE}" />
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
2013-07-25 08:17:18,145 ERROR Failed to insert record for log event in
manager [jdbcManager{ description=XXXXXXXXX, bufferSize=5,
connectionSource=driverManager{ url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXXXXXXX,
username=XXXXXXXXX, passwordHash=XXXXXXXXX }, tableName=XXXXXXXXX,
columns=[ { name=DATE_COLUMN, layout=%X{DATE_VALUE}, literal=null,
timestamp=false } ] }]. java.sql.SQLDataException:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: It seems that if you use the format: 'DD-MMM-YY' it successfully inserts the date but truncates the date so  the time component of the value in the ThreadContext is not preserved.  I suspect it's working this way because 'DD-MMM-YY' happens to match Oracle's NLS settings.  I would like to find a way to do this without truncating the date.

Comment: L=: did you ever got the solution??. Even I am facing the same problem?

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string